# How to use Microsoft Remote Desktop to connect with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I think I am asking a old question for a newer version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I have done my research for past 2 weeks and I didn't find a single blog or guide in SoF or any other source with a working solution to use Windows RDP to access an Ubuntu session.

I have minutely followed this answer: [Can I access Ubuntu from Windows remotely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely)
 - Doesn't works

I have also tried using x11vnc service and made sure than all my services start on boot following this [Error/problem connecting (Windows 10 RDP into XRDP)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797973/error-problem-connecting-windows-10-rdp-into-xrdp) - Doesn't work either.

Closest I reach was this screen:

[image]

And this [Xrdp - Connect Ubuntu Linux Remote Desktop via RDP from Windows](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/xrdp-connect-ubuntu-linux-remote-desktop-via-rdp-from-windows/) - Doesn't work

And all I have reach so far was the following screen trying almost all session type xorg, x11rdp:
[image]

I also, went ahead and made sure that my services are always running following [Systemd service that is always restarted](https://selivan.github.io/2017/12/30/systemd-serice-always-restart.html), and seems like most of the remoting services are doing so, but even that didn't help?

Question: Did anyone recently tried connecting to Ubuntu Session using RDP? What are those posts missing that requires to revise in the newer Ubuntus.

Comment: Good luck and I hope it works for you, I've put more hours than I would care to admit into RDPing into my linux box and to no avail.

Comment: I haven't found how to use RDP with Ubuntu 18.04, but this really helping me to open Ubuntu in full res. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030276/ubuntu-server-18-04-lts-cannot-change-resolution-in-hyper-v/1032132#1032132

Answer (score 1):

To have xrdp working on ubuntu 18.04,  you can multiple choices

*Note : To have this procedure working, you have to run an up to date version of Ubuntu 18.04.4*

You can perform a manual installation by issuing the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp -y
sudo apt-get intall xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04
```

Check this post for more information about this (https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13972)

You can also try to use the easy to use **xrdp-installer-1.1.sh** script that can help automate the installation.  To use the script, you will first have to download it, extract content, make it executable and issue the command with or without needed parameters

Using the script is quite straight forward (Please read the howto use it first in the post http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14093!!!)

**Step 1 - Download the script**

```
wget https://www.c-nergy.be/downloads/xrdp-installer-1.1.zip
```

**Step 2 - Unzip it**

```
unzip xrdp-installer-1.1.zip
```

**Step 3 - Mark it as executable**

```
chmod +x xrdp-installer-1.1.sh
```

**Step 4 - Execute the script with parameters to enable your selected options**

```
./xrdp-installer-1.1.sh -h  (for the help)
./xrdp-installer-1.1.sh     (install xrdp using xrdp ubuntu packages )
./xrdp-installer-1.1.sh -c  (install xrdp from sources )
....
```

As Ubuntu 20.04 is about to be released, expect a new version of the script to be released to fix some minor bugs and include support for Ubuntu 20.04

Please note also that if user A is logged on locally on the PC, the user A will not be able to connect remotely (it will be disconnected after login into the remote session). The user A if connected remotely will not be able to login locally on the machine (login loop).  This is a limitation to be aware of

Hope this help 
Till next time